# Can I export from actuate 8 to jasper reports

Tags: export, jasper-reports, actuate

Is there a way to export from an older version of actuate (actuate 8) to jasper reports which offers much nicer features. The problem is rewriting/redeveloping all the reports would take so much time the cost savings is not there.

The format of the reports is in the proprietary binary format.

Answer (score 0):

I welcome all of you who are interested in migration of Actuate reports to Jasper to try our solution Reporting2Jasper at http://reporting.dio-soft.com/services/reporting-migration. It is an online application which converts .bas and .xml files to .jrxml, including datatype, layout and formulas conversion. Currently the free Demo version is available.

We would appreciate any feedback regarding the application’s performance.